# Problems with AutoLayout, Safe Areas and NavigationBar

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

I'm having nasty problems with using auto layout in presence of a navigationBar. My goal is to position the view behind the navigation bar and the toolbar. Basically, I don't want to constrain my subview to either the navigation bar or the toolbar. This way, if I make them disappear, my view will stay where it is.

However, no matter what I do, it seems to fail.

Here is my code, inside the viewController's viewDidLoad():

```
view.addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

My understanding was that in this way I could ignore the safeareas. However, it seems that the bottom anchor is correct while the topAnchor coincides with the view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor.

The view controller is the root of a navigationController.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Even using a simple UIView it doesn't work. The view.topAnchor is the same as the view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor. So, how can I pin my collectionView to the "real" view.topAnchor? Why such a simple thing should be so complicated... without navigatonBar, this works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

So, after countless hours I figured this out.

If you are using an opaque navigation bar, you have to modify this property of the ViewController:

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

Without it, when the navigation bar is visible, the view's topAnchor corresponds to the bottom of the navigation bar (same thing with the view's frame).